# Python code to find new temperature records

Tags: python, dictionary, readfile, analysis

I need some help with a problem for my python class.

First I'm supposed make a function to read a csv with months and highest temperature that month. Put these in a dictionary with month as key and temp as value. This I managed fine.

```
def fileTodict(filename):         
    dict = {}                     
    file = open(filename,"r")         
    for line in file:
        i = line.split(",")        
        month = i[0]                 
        temp = i[1]                  
        x = len(temp)-1              
        temp = temp[0:x]             
        dict[month]=float(temp)    
    return dict
```

But now I'm supposed to read a new file with month, day, temp and make a new function that reads this file line by line. If it finds a new all time high temp for a given month it should print for example "New record found for January". And to this for all the 365 lines in the file representing all the days in a given year.

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: You've explained what you need, but not why you need our help with it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code-writing, tutorial, or homework service. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research, and a description of the _specific_ issue you're having with your attempt. This will help us to understand how to help you better

Comment: So frustrating being stuck like this. Feel that I will think "of course" when I see some code that can solve this problem. I just can't conceptualize how to compare a set of temperatures for days of one month with the previous max temperature that month. Tried to make a dictionary with month as key and a new dictionary as value. The second dictionary containing the day(key), temp(value).

Comment: @NedimKasumacic Whenever you post a question on stack overflow about reading data from a file you need to post a sample of the file. Do ***not*** post the entire csv file, only a small excerpt (4 to 8 lines). This way, other people can see how the data is formatted.

Comment: Why read csv by hand and not use a library, e.g. `pandas`?